# Stopwatch in Java with a resetting function

Tags: java, sip, sip-servlet

I have implemented a SIP Servlet, where I receive two types of messages from the clients. I can receive either a high priority message and low priority message, which I separate when I'm reading the URIs of the messages as shown in the code below. I have to implement a basic stopwatch, which increments the "count" integer declared in code below. How do I make such a stopwatch and resetting it ?.

```
protected void doRequest(SipServletRequest reqfromclient) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, java.io.IOException {
    if( reqfromclient.getMethod().equals("MESSAGE") ) {
        String MESSAGE = reqfromclient.getContent().toString();
        System.out.println("The arrived message is " + MESSAGE);          

        // Assign the callee URI
        String URICallee = reqfromclient.getTo().getURI().toString();

         //Assign the caller URI
        String URICaller = reqfromclient.getFrom().getURI().toString();


        //DECLARE STOPWATCH
        int count = 0;


        // Now the Highprio and Lowprio alerts have to be separated
        if(URICallee.endsWith("policeHigh.com")) {
            // RESET STOPWATCH
            //START THE STOPWATCH. INCREMENT COUNT EVERY SECOND
        }

        else if(URICallee.endsWith("policeLow.com")) {              
            if(count == 21) {                   
            //something
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Guava has a `Stopwatch` class...

Comment: It sounds like you want to know the time between two events. The first event is when you get the high-priority message. What is the second event, that is, under what conditions do you report the value of the stopwatch?

Comment: The point is that, when I receive a high priority message, I have to start the stopwatch. When an another high priority message arrives, I'll reset the stopwatch and start it again (count from 0). If a low priority message arrives instead, it will wait the stopwatch until count = 20 sec before doing anything, since it is low priority.

Comment: Do you want to take an action when a certain amount of time has passed? You haven't specified how this information is to be used, and determines the form of the answer.

Comment: The whole point is that I have to send this message in a JSP, so the message will be displayed in a web page. A high priority message has to be displayed 20 seconds without getting interruptet by a new incoming low priority message. But a low priority message can get interrupted by an incorming high priority message whenever a high prio message arrives. That's why I have to delay the low priority messages using stopwatch. When the count reaches 21 seconds, the low priority message has to get displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute some arbitrary code based on a timer, use the `ServletTimer` class which can be created from the `TimerService`. There are several parts to this:

- When you want to set a timer, obtain a reference to the [`TimerService`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/apirefs.1111/e17883/javax/servlet/sip/TimerService.html).
- Use the `TimerService` to create a `ServletTimer` with the required timeout period.
- Store the ID of the `ServletTimer` somewhere (as an attribute in the `SipSession` or `SipApplicationSession`).
- If the timer needs to be cancelled, retrieve the timer ID from the session, retrieve the timer using `sipApplicationSession.getTimer(id)` and call `cancel()` on it.
- You will need some class that implements the `TimerListener` interface. It can be your servlet class if you wish. Implement the `timeout` method with the logic that your application needs to perform when the timeout expires. As discussed in [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/apirefs.1111/e17883/javax/servlet/sip/TimerService.html), declare the class to be a `listener` in the SIP deployment descriptor.
- Optional: when your call is over, call `sipApplicationSession.invalidate()`, which will cancel any outstanding timers.

A simple example is shown [here](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~ss2020/sipservlet/fwdOnNoRsp.htm). The example is flawed in that it stores the `ServletTimer` as a field of the servlet class, so it will get overwritten as subsequent calls come in. Storing the ID as an attribute of the `SipApplicationSession` will keep it from getting overwritten.